# Does "fixed" get cleaned up properly if an Exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe

I'd assume that `fixed` is implemented similar to `using`/`try..finally` in that if the block terminates early (via return or throwing an Exception), the pointer gets properly cleaned up ("unfixed" so that the GC can do its work again).

However, I'm not seeing such a guarantee in the [fixed documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement), so I'm wondering if there is some form of official guarantee somewhere, or if I should introduce a `try..catch` in every fixed block.

```
unsafe void FooUnsafe()
{
    var str = "Foo";
    try
    {
        fixed (char* pStr = str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Char: " + (*pStr));
            throw new Exception("Test");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception when working with {str}: {ex.Message}");      
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointer cannot live longer than the resource that it points to because C# protects it from happening because of [Dangling Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). So if you point to a local variable, then it will definitely be disposed once the variable goes out of scope. In this situation, once the `FooUnsafe` returns.

Comment: I think documentation (and specification) are pretty clear. Specification says that object is pinned "for the duration of the fixed statement". So whenever control flow leaves fixed statement, either naturally or as a result of exception - variable is unpinned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As commented by FCin**

> Pointer cannot live longer than the resource that it points to because
>   C# protects it from happening because of Dangling Pointer. So if you
>   point to a local variable, then it will definitely be disposed once
>   the variable goes out of scope. In this situation, once the FooUnsafe
>   returns.

**Also noted by JuanR**

[fixed Statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)

> After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are
>   unpinned and subject to garbage collection.

However, lets try and prove it with a simple example, and some snippets of information around the Interwebs

```
private static unsafe void Main()
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Total Memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");

   var arr = new int[100000];

   Console.WriteLine($"Total Memory after new : {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");

   try
   {

      fixed (int* p = arr)
      {
         *p = 1;
         throw new Exception("rah");
      }

   }
   catch 
   {
   }

   Console.WriteLine($"Generation: {GC.GetGeneration(arr)}, Total Memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");

   arr = null;
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   Console.WriteLine("Total Memory: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
   Console.Read();
}
```

**Results**

```
Total Memory: 29948
Total Memory after new: 438172
Generation: 2, Total Memory: 438172
Total Memory: 29824
```

You will notice in IL the `finally` and `ldnull`

```
.try
{

   // [23 14 - 23 26]
   IL_0043: ldloc.0      // arr
   IL_0044: dup          
   IL_0045: stloc.2      // V_2
   IL_0046: brfalse.s    IL_004d
   IL_0048: ldloc.2      // V_2
   IL_0049: ldlen        
   IL_004a: conv.i4      
   IL_004b: brtrue.s     IL_0052
   IL_004d: ldc.i4.0     
   IL_004e: conv.u       
   IL_004f: stloc.1      // p
   IL_0050: br.s         IL_005b
   IL_0052: ldloc.2      // V_2
   IL_0053: ldc.i4.0     
   IL_0054: ldelema      [mscorlib]System.Int32
   IL_0059: conv.u       
   IL_005a: stloc.1      // p

   ...

} // end of .try
finally
{

   IL_006a: ldnull       
   IL_006b: stloc.2      // V_2
   IL_006c: endfinally   
} // end of finally
```

An interesting note, is you wont always see the finally as the compiler will optimize it out in certain situations

[LocalRewriter_FixedStatement.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LocalRewriter/LocalRewriter_FixedStatement.cs#L49-L54) in the Roslyn source

```
// In principle, the cleanup code (i.e. nulling out the pinned variables) is always
// in a finally block.  However, we can optimize finally away (keeping the cleanup
// code) in cases where both of the following are true:
//   1) there are no branches out of the fixed statement; and
//   2) the fixed statement is not in a try block (syntactic or synthesized).
if (IsInTryBlock(node) || HasGotoOut(rewrittenBody))
{
```

i.e even if it lives in a method like this

```
private static unsafe void test(int[] arr)
{
   fixed (int* p = arr)
   {
      *p = 1;
   }
}
```

You will notice

```
.method private hidebysig static void 
   test(
   int32[] arr
   ) cil managed 
{
   .maxstack 2
   .locals init (
   [0] int32* p,
   [1] int32[] pinned V_1
   )

   ...

   IL_001e: ldnull       
   IL_001f: stloc.1      // V_1

   // [54 7 - 54 8]
   IL_0020: ret          

} // end of method MyGCCollectClass::test
```

**Some background**

[Standard ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)

> II.7.1.2 pinned The signature encoding for pinned shall appear only in
>   signatures that describe local variables (§II.15.4.1.3). While a
>   method with a pinned local variable is executing, the VES shall not
>   relocate the object to which the local refers. That is, if the
>   implementation of the CLI uses a garbage collector that moves objects,
>   the collector shall not move objects that are referenced by an active
>   pinned local variable.
>
> [Rationale: If unmanaged pointers are used to dereference managed
>   objects, these objects shall be pinned. This happens, for example,
>   when a managed object is passed to a method designed to operate with
>   unmanaged data. end rationale]
>
> VES = Virtual Execution System CLI = Common Language Infrastructure
>   CTS = Common Type System

Lastly, The *JITer* and the *CLR* aside, most of the ground work for pinning is done by the *GC*

> In effect the GC has to get out of the way and leave the pinned local
>   variable alone for the life-time of the method. Normally the GC is
>   concerned about which objects are live or dead so that it knows what
>   it has to clean up. But with pinned objects it has to go one step
>   further, not only must it not clean up the object, but it must not
>   move it around. Generally the GC likes to relocate objects around
>   during the Compact Phase to make memory allocations cheap, but pinning
>   prevents that as the object is being accessed via a pointer and
>   therefore its memory address has to remain the same.

Obviously your main concern here is the Fragmentation Problem, and you are worried that the *GC* wont be able to clean it up.

[image]

However as seen by the example (and you can play with it your self), as soon as the `ary` goes out of scope and the fixed is finalized the GC will eventually free it completely.

---

> **Note** : I am **not** a reputable source, and i could find no *Official Confirmation* however i thought these snippets of information i found
>   might be of interest all the same

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth look, including the Roslyn source. I think this just confirms what is the only sane design choice anyway, that a fixed pointer does get cleaned up on Exceptions as well.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are
>   unpinned and subject to garbage collection.

[fixed Statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)

Answer (score 2):

It is based on the scope.

Within the `fixed` block, in the handle table the object will be "pinned" and the GC will not relocate the variable unpredictably.

When an exception is thrown, you will be out of the fixed scope and the GC will not consider that memory location pinned.

I don't know internal implementation, but the GC might check the execution point of certain thread and based on that find out if it is allowed to relocate or not (i.e based on if within a fixed block or not).

You don't need to have it within `try/catch/finally` block.

Comment: `GC will not consider that memory location pinned` any source? I think this is the whole question, whether GC will consider it pinned or not.

Comment: Yeah. I see in IL that there seems to be a finally block (at least an endfinally instruction, not sure if that's the same), but I don't want to rely on observed rather than documented functionality if possible.